# How to display the suffix of long strings in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I've got a Pandas `DataFrame` containing paths on a file server, which are fairly long strings (~150 characters). With the default `options.display.max_colwidth`, the display is the same for all values, since most of these files are rooted in the same directory. I could of course widen `max_colwidth`, but I'd rather just see the last N characters.

Is the a way to make Pandas show the *last N characters* of long strings, instead of truncating after the first N characters?

Comment: Is possible use helper column? `df[col] = df['long_str_col'].str[-20:]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is create helper column with last `N` characters by [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str):

```
df['col'] = df['long_str_col'].str[-N:]
```

Comment: Not ideal, but it might be a practical workaround if there's no way to intercept the display representation

Comment: I think it is not implemented, unfortunately. I check docs also, but nothing :(

Comment: I couldn't find it either :(.. I'll leave it open for another little while to see if someone comes up with something, else I'll accept this one